# Someone knows how to change the background color on an animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, google-colaboratory, celluloid

I'm doing an animation with celluloid.Camera in Google Colab, for that it show the animation I'm using this code segment:

```
camera = Camera(fig)

# Create animation
anim = camera.animate()
# Inline display
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

And I get this:

[image]

I've tried using the next lines:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8), facecolor='black')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')
ax.set_facecolor('black')
```

But it doesn't work. I want the entire background to be black.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I only want that the white background that see on the image to be black. For the animation I'm using celluloid.Camera(). Sorry if I don't make myself understood, I'm new on this.